# HTML Table Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, formatting, tabular

I have a table of balances (for payments) that need to be displayed. However, if, the payment is past due, there needs to be an asterisk next to the amount. Right now, it's displaying like this:
[image: Current image display]

But I want it to look more like this (please ignore value differences and color/size differences):

[image: Desired image display]

In particular, I want all the numbers to line up at the decimal point, and the asterisk to sort of be tacked onto the end, not affecting the layout of the actual numbers. As you can see, the way it is displaying currently, since it is right-aligned, the asterisk pushes over the numbers. If I left-align the table cell, then the numbers don't line up at the decimal point properly (for example, the total's decimal point, since it is 6 digits would not line up with the 5 digit installment line). How can I get the columns to follow the format of the second example (the one with the blue background)?

Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Comment: Can u show us your html code? How are you including the `*` in a `span` ?

Comment: Use three separate columns for the integer digits, decimal point, and the decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

The practical solution is to add a column that contains just an asterisk or a space. Then you can simply right-align the column that contains the amount.

This would still leave a minor layout problem, which can be seen in the second screenshot of the question: if you use bold face for some rows, things don’t quite align. The reason is that a bold face letter is often somewhat wider than a corresponding normal face letter. Consider using other highlighting methods, such as distinctive background color, that do not have such effects.

In theory, both HTML and CSS have tools for aligning a column to a decimal point. However, despite having been in the specs for many years, they have not been implemented in browsers.

An alternative, clumsier and less reliable, practical approach would be to put the asterisk in a `span` element, declared with `display: inline-block`, with some specific width set, and with the same width set as right padding on amount cells that do not have an asterisk. But the separate column approach is simple, and more logical: the asterisk is really an information item of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Align the text to the left & top of the box.  That wouldn't line them up @ the decimal though.  To line them up at the decimal would be a bit more of a a challenge.

You could do something like this.

[span dollar][span change][span asterisk]

Just make sure to set a definite width for the asterisk and align text right on dollar, and left on change & asterisk.